# Button and Table dropdown shows duplicate values in Laravel 8

Tags: php, html, css, laravel

[image]

I want to show no duplicates of the dropdown, I already set distinct in the controller query builder. Here's the blade view for this dropdown:

```
            <div class="btn-group">
                <button class="ml-2.5 mt-2 btn btn-primary " type="button">
                  Notifications: {{ $notifications }}
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="mt-2 btn btn-lg btn-primary dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-split" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                  <span class="visually-hidden">Toggle Dropdown</span>
                </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                @foreach ($getmahasiswa as $requests)
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href={{ url('/dashboard/nameasrequest',$requests->id_mhs) }}>{{ $requests->name }} | {{ $requests->id_mhs }}</a></li>
                @endforeach
                </ul>
            </div>
```

[image]

This dropdown table automatically toggled all the data that have the same name, i want it to open normally one by one. Here's the blade view for the dropdown table:

```
<div class="container">
<table class="table table-condensed"  id="myTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Mata Kuliah</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
                        @foreach($getmahasiswa as $collapse)
                        
    <tbody class="panel">
        <tr data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#demo{{$collapse->id_mhs}}" data-bs-parent="#myTable">
            <strong>
                <td>{{ $collapse->mk }}</td>
            </strong>
        </tr>
        <tr id="demo{{$collapse->id_mhs}}" class="collapse">
            <td colspan="6" class="hiddenRow">
                <div>
                    <strong>{{$collapse->name}}</strong>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="align-self-end">
                <div>
                    <button type="button" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal{{$collapse->id_mhs}}" class="mr-3 text-sm bg-blue-500 hover:bg-green-700 text-white py-1 px-2 rounded focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline">
                        <a href=# >APPLY ALL</a>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </td>
            <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal{{$collapse->id_mhs}}" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Mata Kuliah</h5>
                            <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                                            @foreach($getmahasiswa as $collapses)
                                            {{$collapses->mk}}
                            <br>
                                            @endforeach
                                        
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
                        @endforeach
                    
    </table>
</div>
```

and here's the controller to fetch the data for both of views

```
$lr = DB::table('lr2')->get();
        $notifications = DB::table('lr2')->distinct()->count('id_mhs');
        $getmahasiswa = DB::table('lr2')->distinct()->select('lr2.id_mhs', 'users.name', 'lr2.mk')
        ->join('users', 'lr2.id_mhs', '=', 'users.id')->get();
        return view('dashboard', compact('lr', 'notifications', 'getmahasiswa'));
```